# How to add a CKEditor custom config file to XPages?

Tags: javascript, dojo, ckeditor, xpages, ssjs

I am trying to add a custom config file to all the RichText items in my application but I can't figure out how to refernce the config file correctly in the dojo attribute. I want to reference it releative to the database.

```
<xp:dojoAttribute name="customConfig" value="cke_custom_config.js"></xp:dojoAttribute>
```

[image]

```
<xp:inputRichText id="inputRichText2" value="#{cd.Body}">
  <xp:this.dojoAttributes>
    <xp:dojoAttribute name="customConfig" value="cke_custom_config.js"></xp:dojoAttribute>
  </xp:this.dojoAttributes>
</xp:inputRichText>
```

In my example above the config file is referenced to: 
http://server/xsp/.ibmxspres/domino/ckeditor/cke_custom_config.js?t=G44E

How can I change the path to the config file to point to "WebContent/cke_custom_config.js" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<xp:inputRichText id="inputRichTextBody"
    value="#{cd.Body}">
    <xp:this.dojoAttributes>
        <xp:dojoAttribute name="customConfig"
            value="${facesContext.externalContext.request.contextPath}/cke_custom_config.js?open">
        </xp:dojoAttribute>
    </xp:this.dojoAttributes>
</xp:inputRichText>
```

The EL part added before the *cke_custom_config.js?open* is the path to the current database.

Comment: thanks. why do I need to get rid of the timestamp, is that for preventing cache?

Comment: I think parameters will work if using "cke_custom_config.js?open"

Comment: @ThomasAdrian: Ok, changed my answer